# Testing JavaScript Running in an IFrame

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, iframe, jasmine

I need to test JavaScript with Jasmine. The code under test needs to think it's running in an IFrame. I see examples of tests creating IFrames but don't see any docs or examples of executing the code from within the IFrame.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Add your own efforts such as coding approaches and docs research.